# Как проинициализировать объекты enum вне класса

Tags: java

1.Почему в конструктор объекта Enum нельзя передать значение позже (не в самом классе где он автоматически создается)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.Почему в енамах нет hashcode equals?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы этот сам конструктор-то определили?

Comment: Не помещайте в вопрос картинки, помещайте свой код, сообщения об ошибках и т. п. в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## По первому вопросу:

Используйте следующую запись:

```
Cat cat = Cat.Tom;
```

Если вы хотите добавить конструкторы, то их нужно объявлять неосредтсвенно в самом enum:

```
public enum Cat {
    TOM(1),
    BOB(2);

    private int number;

    Cat(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

Вызывать конструкторы вне определения enum нельзя, так как грубо говоря enum - список именованых констант.

Другими словами, можете воспринимать enum как нечто вроде этого:

```
public final class Cat extends java.lang.Enum {
   public final static Cat TOM = new Cat(1);
   public final static Cat BOB = new Cat(2);

   private int number;
   private Cat(int number) {
       this.number = number;
   }
   public int getNumber() {
       return number;
   }
}
```

## По второму вопросу

Enum классы имеют hashCode и equals, просто их нельзя переопределить.

Можете убедится в этом вызвав:

```java
int hash = Cat.TOM.hashCode();
```

и

```java
boolean val = Cat.TOM.equals(Cat.BOB);
```

Comment: @CapitaNemo дополнил ответ.